# How do i Implement a Talend job to delete the records in a given table for a given district on a given date?

Tags: etl, talend

I have used a tmssqlconnection and tmssqlrow component.How do i pass the contexts and run the job?

Comment: Kindly show the sample job design. And explain detail regarding your question.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your tmySql row like this and use the below query

Query:- Delete from table where state = ? and date = ?

Advanced Settings:- UsePreparedstatement and define the no of parameters needed.

so the index 1 will be substitued in first question mark and index 2 will be substitued in second question mark.

Please follow the below screen shots. I did it quickly for tOraclerow. You can do the same for tMysqlrow

[image: Delete statement]

[image: Advanced Settings configuration]

[image: Context Variable]